# how to perform action on following range slider in selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a range slider with the HTML as following:

```
<div class="col-12">
<input type="range" name="range" ng-mousedown="onrangeclick=true;" ng-model="x.amount" min="0" max="500000" step="1000" autocomplete="off" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-step ng-touched">

</div>
```

Now I have tried all possible ways to click on slider but i am failed to so. I just couldn't click on slider to make it move leftwards.

The method i wrote for slider is following.

```
public void RangeSlider(int count, string ArrowOption, string locator)
        {
            IWebElement slider = waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(locator)));
            slider.Click();

            if (ArrowOption == "LEFT")
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    slider.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowLeft);
                }
            }
            else if (ArrowOption == "RIGHT")
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    slider.SendKeys("{RIGHT}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Action class MoveToElement method with offset.

```
//Get the slider element
IWebElement slider = waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(locator)));
//Get element size
Dimension dimensions = slider.Size();


Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element,dimensions.Width,1).click().perform();
```